# I'm looking for a matrix $M$ with $\det(M)=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

In order to show that $(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)(A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2)=  \alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2+\delta^2$ with $a,b,c,d,A,B,C,D,\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta \in \mathbb Z$.

I would like to find a matrix with determinant $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ in order to multiply the matrix with another with determinant $A^2+B^+C^2+D^2$.

Comment: $\left[\begin{matrix}a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2&1\\0&1\end{matrix}\right]$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make an answer. This is about quaternions with integer coefficients; that is, take
$$ (a + bi + cj + dk)(A+Bi+Cj+Dk)=(\alpha + \beta i + \gamma j + \delta k) $$
Then your relationship holds. To make them determinants, use one of the (several) representations of quaternions as 4 by 4 matrices,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations

Comment: You were quicker than me on that one and you actually deserve all the credit! That's why I deleted my answer.

Comment: @C.Falcon alright, if you prefer it that way; and thank you for your kind words. It takes long enough to type these things that simultaneous answers happen pretty often, I don't think it necessary for a difference of seconds to mean one is deleted.

Comment: I later saw that you made an early comment and since I have not really much insight to provide in my answer, I decided that way.

Comment: @C.Falcon, also, France plays  Ireland on Sunday. Not really related to this question or website, I admit

Comment: I am not really into soccer, but on my way back to Bordeaux last week, I met some Irish supporters, they were really enthuastic and respectful!

Comment: @C.Falcon you are allowed. I just answered your question from late May, I will look for some examples for that.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix, where $i = \sqrt{-1}$,
\begin{pmatrix}
a+ib & -c+id\\
c+id & a-ib
\end{pmatrix}
works. When we multiply two matrices of the above form, we get a matrix of the same form.